# Do Marionette CollectionViews have a templateContext?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, mustache

I can provide a templateContext to other Marionette views, but the CollectionView does not seem to take advantage of it when provided.  Do Marionette CollectionViews have a templateContext?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CollectionViews use the templateContext parameter.  However, CollectionViews do NOT respect the renderer specified by Marionette.View.setRenderer.  So, if one specifies a "global" renderer - in my case to use Mustache:

```
Marionette.View.setRenderer((template, viewToRender) => {
    return Mustache.render(template, viewToRender);
});
```

the templateContext is essentially ignored.